# ViewPager of views (not fragments) as header of a gridview (Etsy's StaggeredGridView) in a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-gridview

So, I'm in a situation where I want to add a ViewPager of views (not fragments) as the header of a gridview in a fragment, but my ViewPager doesn't appear when I set it as my headerview. I'm currently using Etsy's StaggeredGridView to allow my gridview to have a header, and I'm using a PagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter to be able to scroll through views instead of fragments. I was going to just use fragments, but I wasn't sure if this would be good since, I assume, that would be considered as having nested fragments, which are only supported in 4.2+ and through the support library: my app supports 4.0 and above, and at the moment, I'm using native fragments.

I also tried setting a view programatically, but still nothing shows.

I set a toast in the ViewPager to see if anything is actually getting created, and the toast shows up as expected, but still no header. The view that I'm attempting to inflate shouldn't be the problem because if I use it as a header on its own it shows. Here's what  I have so far:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //inflate fragment which contains the gridview. Have a pointer to the gridview.
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) v.findViewById(R.id.dishesGridView);

    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_header, container, false);
    ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) header.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //list of views to test header
    final List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    views.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_header, null));

    mPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
        public View getView(int position) {
            return views.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
            View v = getView(position);
            ((ViewPager)collection).addView(v);
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Hello ViewPager",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0 == (View) arg1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return views.size();
        }
    });
    mGridView.addHeaderView(mPager);
    return v;
}
```

Here's the view_pager_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here's the menu_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout      
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/resHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <com.platey.IonPlatey.RectangleImageView
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="ResType Here"
    android:textColor="#d82727"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reason:

Basically the issue is caused by `ViewPager` `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The `match_parent` is wrong here for sure, because you don't want the header to fill entire parent. But regardless of that - `match_parent` will not work here in `StaggeredGridView`.

This is the same as in standard `ListView` items etc. - `match_parent` is not allowed and it will be replaced with just `wrap_content` while performing layout.
Unfortunately `wrap_content` is not supported by `ViewPager` because `ViewPager` cannot wrap it's content (it is not aware of children size).

### Solution:

You have two ways to properly display a `ViewPager` there:

1. Just specify a static height (for example `50dp`)
2. Extend your `ViewPager` and perform your own measuring if you don't want static height.

### Screenshots

Here is also a screenshots with `match_parent`. You can see that ViewPager is nor displayed (has zero height):

[image]

and with static height:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: You, sir, are awesome. Your answer was very clear and thorough. I never knew you couldn't use match_parent since in my menu_header.xml I was using match_parent as the height for my relative layout. I also use this in other places with no problems. I guess I mistakenly assumed that these header layouts became the children of some new view created by calling addHeaderView, which in hindsight still shouldn't. I guess my other header layout worked because the children of my relative layout had fixed heights. Anyway,thanks.

Comment: Oh, wait, nevermind, you said that the match_parent would automatically be changed to wrap_content. That's why my other views worked.

Comment: @Maciej What If I want That height as programmatically.? I mean Devicewidth / 2?

Comment: @GreenRobo you can try using `getLayoutParams()` on the header view and setting its `height` to desired value